# How insert a date and time in sqlite from the current date and time of the system?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, time

I am a newbie in Android programming; this is the first time i'm using SQLite.
How could I insert the time and date in SQLite when I click a button. The button unlock and  lock .. for example I unlocked the door, then as I click the  button the date and time when I clicked it will be inserted in the database.

Comment: Are you using Qt to develop your application for android?

Comment: nope sir. i'm still new in developing an android app.